Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' in react native cli
When I am setting up my environment for the react native cli project it was working fine but when I am running again after some time it will produce below error.
Multiple build operations failed.
      java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\c7e26f7d3c2fc1a6636ff1467fc77795\transformed\jetified-fbjni-0.6.0\prefab\modules\fbjni\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so: not a regular file
      java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5f7281d6477ab96878ec36c791b9af0e\transformed\jetified-hermes-android-0.74.2-debug\prefab\modules\libhermes\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libhermes.so: not a regular file
      java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f\transformed\jetified-react-android-0.74.2-debug\prefab\modules\folly_runtime\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libfolly_runtime.so: not a regular file
   > java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\c7e26f7d3c2fc1a6636ff1467fc77795\transformed\jetified-fbjni-0.6.0\prefab\modules\fbjni\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so: not a regular file
   > java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5f7281d6477ab96878ec36c791b9af0e\transformed\jetified-hermes-android-0.74.2-debug\prefab\modules\libhermes\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libhermes.so: not a regular file
   > java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f\transformed\jetified-react-android-0.74.2-debug\prefab\modules\folly_runtime\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libfolly_runtime.so: not a regular file

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 16s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > Multiple build operations failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\c7e26f7d3c2fc1a6636ff1467fc77795\transformed\jetified-fbjni-0.6.0\prefab\modules\fbjni\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so: not a regular file java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5f7281d6477ab96878ec36c791b9af0e\transformed\jetified-hermes-android-0.74.2-debug\prefab\modules\libhermes\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libhermes.so: not a regular file java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f\transformed\jetified-react-android-0.74.2-debug\prefab\modules\folly_runtime\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libfolly_runtime.so: not a regular file > java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\c7e26f7d3c2fc1a6636ff1467fc77795\transformed\jetified-fbjni-0.6.0\prefab\modules\fbjni\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so: not a regular file > java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5f7281d6477ab96878ec36c791b9af0e\transformed\jetified-hermes-android-0.74.2-debug\prefab\modules\libhermes\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libhermes.so: not a regular file > java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\abhin\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f\transformed\jetified-react-android-0.74.2-debug\prefab\modules\folly_runtime\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libfolly_runtime.so: not a regular file * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 16s.


any updates on this?
